# Wordpress PODS display content from a post

Tags: wordpress

I've recently started using Wordpress PODS plugin and I'm having a little trouble displaying some basic content. I can display custom fields content just fine using the following:

```
<?php
$field_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ‘my_field_name’, true );
echo $field_name; ?>
```

However I can't get basic stuff such as the following:

- title (which in regular posts it’s just `the_title();`)
- content (which in regular posts it’s just `the_content();`)
- featured image

Can someone please help me figure out how to pull the title, content and featured image from a POD?

Comment: It is insane to me that 5 years later there still isn't a simple example of this on the Pods website.

Answer (score 1):

`pod-type-slug` should be replaced by the slug of your pod type. The `pod-slug` is the slug of the specific pod content you created:

```
//Pods->display has been deprecated since Pods version 2.0 with no alternative available according to a warning when trying to use this function:
$pod = pods('pod-type-slug', "pod-slug");

$pod->display('title')
$pod->display('post_content')
```

etc.

You can also use the default WordPress functionality:

```
$pod = pods('pod-type-slug', "pod-slug");

$row = $pod->row();

//print the pod content:
echo $row->post_content;

get_the_post_thumbnail($row['ID']);
```

Comment: You didn't define the `$pod` variable in this example.

Comment: Pods->display has been **deprecated** since Pods version 2.0 with no alternative available.

Answer (score 0):

After a frustrating hour of Googling and looking through their examples, there didn't seem to be a single source of how to get a Pod's content or custom field. The answer above helped me a bit, but wasn't well explained.

In your `wp-content/plugins` folder, create a new folder called `podutils` and create a php file called `PodUtils.php`.

Copy/paste this class into that file:

```
<?php 
//Class to get WordPress Pod data:
class PodUtils {

    //get WordPress Pod Object: 
    public static function GetPodObject($podType, $podSlug) {
        //for use with Pods WP Plugin (https://pods.io/):
        if(function_exists("pods")) {
            $pod = pods($podType, $podSlug)->row();
            return $pod;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }

    //get the content from a WordPress Pod: 
    public static function GetPodContent($podType, $podSlug) {
        $pod = PodUtils::GetPodObject($podType, $podSlug);      
        if($pod !== false) {
            return $pod["post_content"];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //get a custom field from a WordPress Pod:  
    public static function GetPodMeta($podType, $podSlug, $metaName, $isSingle = true) {
        $pod = PodUtils::GetPodObject($podType, $podSlug);
        if($pod !== false) {
            return get_post_meta($pod["ID"], $metaName, $isSingle);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

To use the class with static methods, do so as follows:

Include the PodUtils.php file in the php file you want to use it:

`require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/podutils/PodUtils.php';`

Get content:

`$strPodContent = PodUtils::GetPodContent('pod-type', 'pod-item-slug');`

Get meta (custom field you added to a pod type):

`$strPodMeta = PodUtils::GetPodMeta('pod-type', 'pod-item-slug', 'custom-meta-name');`

This can easily be changed to an object that you instantiate with public functions, or a plugin of its own.